# Time varies in postgres server and excel

Tags: excel, postgresql

I am trying a query which groups the data by months.

```
test_db=# select date_trunc('month', install_ts) AS month, count(id) AS count from api_booking group by month order by month asc;         
 month                  | count 
------------------------+-------
 2016-08-01 00:00:00+00 |   297
 2016-09-01 00:00:00+00 |  2409
 2016-10-01 00:00:00+00 |  2429
 2016-11-01 00:00:00+00 |  3512
(4 rows)
```

This is the output in my postgres db shell.

How ever, when I try this query in excel, this is the output,

```
 month                  | count 
------------------------+-------
 2016-07-31 17:00:00+00 |   297
 2016-08-31 17:00:00+00 |  2409
 2016-09-30 17:00:00+00 |  2429
 2016-10-31 17:00:00+00 |  3512
(4 rows)
```

The problem is I think excel is understanding date format in some different timezone. 
So, How can I tell excel to read it correctly?
OR any solution to this problem?

Comment: can you specify query for excel?.. you can set timezone for user or od or server

Comment: I was using the same query. But I figured it out, `select date_trunc('month', install_ts) at time zone 'GMT' AS month, count(id) AS count from table1`. It was the issue with time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
select date(date_trunc('month', install_ts)) AS month, count(id) AS count from api_booking
```

The date()  strips out the time from a date with a time.